# Unified initialization syntax in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

The question about “unified initialization syntax” in C++11.

Is it legal to initialize the struct with the next syntax in C++11 (look at lines #128-137)? Or POD is still actual?

http://pastebin.com/GMZ5QDmR

The problem with MSVC 2013 compiler. This example compiles successfully, but crashes with bad function call exception. That told to me the std::function object not initialized properly.

By the way, the ICC 13.0 can not compile the code in the example.

> example.cpp(130): error #2084: designator may not specify a non-POD (Plain Old Data) subobject

Is it defect in compilers? Or with compilers all is ok, and such approach is not compliant with C++11?

Here is short example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct dispatcher_t {};
struct binder_t {};

struct factories_t
{
    std::function< std::unique_ptr< dispatcher_t > () > m_disp_factory;
    std::function< std::unique_ptr< binder_t > () > m_bind_factory;
};

std::unique_ptr< dispatcher_t >
create_dispatcher()
{
    return std::unique_ptr< dispatcher_t >( new dispatcher_t() );
}

std::unique_ptr< binder_t >
create_binder()
{
    return std::unique_ptr< binder_t >( new binder_t() );
}

void main()
{
    factories_t f{
        []() { return create_dispatcher(); },
        []() { return create_binder(); }
    };
}
```

Comment: Use markdown to put the code here, don't use pastebin

Comment: That's quite a long piece of code. Please reduce it to the minimal example, then edit question to show it using the `code markup`.

Comment: Is it not possible to put a SSCCE here? Sorry, I will not walk through tons of code!

Comment: I've updated the question. Added short example...

Comment: The signature of `main` is incorrect; otherwise your code is fine.

Comment: You want to say that only GCC has implemented C++11 standard correctly? And MSVC 2013, ICC 13.0 are wrong? Where in the C++11 standard said that initialization with {} should correctly initialize non-POD members? Can you point me out, please.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler - "Partial" in "General initializer lists" for ICC 13 is probably why it doesn't compile this.

Comment: BTW, people call this "uniform initialization", not "unified"  I believe.

Comment: You shouldn't need the lambdas in the initialization of `f`, just the functions directly.

Comment: Confirmed it compiles file with Clang 3.4, GCC 4.8.2 _and_ ICC 14.0.3. ICC 13 is more than a year old.

Comment: Your example compiles and runs on VS2013 without any exceptions, even if I add `f.m_disp_factory(); f.m_bind_factory();` after initializing `f`

Comment: Small example works on any modern compiler because of it doesn't use capture list in lambdas. For MSVC bug look at full example.

Comment: For explanation of the problem and excerpts from the Standard you can see it: https://plus.google.com/110004778875737593095/posts/bcZgzYFHGqB

Answer (score 2):

First: `void main` is illegal in C++. Use `int main`.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 isn't the star of the C++11 class. Neither is Intel's compiler version 13, because, well, they have version 14. That being said, you can try the [MSVC++ 2013 November CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx), which is a tiny bit better on the language support.

If you want to see if your code is valid, use the latest version of GCC or Clang, both available on [the Greatest Online Compiler Platform in Existence](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com).

The C++ language features are reported on the vendor's websites:

- [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)
- [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)
- [Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)
- [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler)

Any other C++ compiler isn't worth mentioning wrt C++11.

Note that the Standard library features may not be mentioned on these pages.

The feature you are looking usually falls under "(general) initializer lists".